# Can I open a word document and execute find operation using a script?

Tags: windows, vbscript, ms-word, cmd

Can I do this operation in any command line or any scripting language ?

I have a string and I want to search for it in word document exactly as a user would do it.

Steps:

1- I want to open the document.

2- select the text that matches the string I have.

Comment: If you want a more detailed answer than "yes", describe your real world problem/intended solution in more detail.

Comment: edited as required :)

Comment: look at http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2006/08/08/how-can-i-replace-text-in-a-microsoft-word-document.aspx?Redirected=true or http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/04/08/hey-scripting-guy-april-8-2010.aspx to get started.

Comment: VBScript and PowerShell are suitable, CMD not.

Answer (score 1):

You can do  this with [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) or the closed-source but free AutoIt. Both of them can emulate user input and interact with the operating system through special scripting languages.

If you use one of the recent versions of Microsoft Word, [this page](http://diyivorytower.wordpress.com/2011/02/15/use-autohotkey-microsoft-word-and-dopdf-to-grade-papers-electronically/) could help you. It features a short example of how to control Microsoft Word's main interface with AutoHotkey. You'd just have to add some code to press Ctrl-F, input your search string and press the find button.

Alternatively, Ekkehard's links could also be useful if you prefer to directly use Word's macro functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, easy in autoit. This will search & highlight the word "three":

```
#include <Word.au3>

$oWordApp = _WordCreate(@ScriptDir & "\blah.doc")
$oDoc = _WordDocGetCollection($oWordApp, 0)

$FindText = "three"
With $oWordApp.Selection.Find
    .Forward = True
    .ClearFormatting
    .Wrap = 1 ;.Wrap could be $wdFindContinue which is 1
    .Execute($FindText)
EndWith
```